# Where the Smart Contract deployment charges goes?

Tags: contract-deployment, contract-invocation

I'm newbie to Ethereum, and finding answers of some questions that I have.
I have learned about SC deployment that `deploying the contract cost 0.01072934 ether, or about $3.21 USD`

So, where that cost goes? it that goes to miners? or anywhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all ether that is paid for transactions is [rewarded to the miner](https://steemit.com/ethereum/@tomshwom/ethereum-gas-how-it-works) of the block a transaction is included in.

Comment: Does it include contract invocation too? not a transaction

Comment: Yes, because a contract invocation is only done by executing a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

All the gas cost directly goes to miner who mined the blockchain that contains your transaction.

Check out the field `Block Reward` of [this block](https://etherscan.io/block/5816964) (5816964) which is 3 + 0.0619125919 ether. It is the sum total of 3 ether static reward and Tx fees (gas cost) in decimals.

Comment: My question is for SC deployment not a transaction.

Comment: Contract deployment is also a transaction. Anything which change the state of blockchain is a Tx.

Comment: So, what miner do in a contract deployment? what they verifies?

Comment: Anything which change the state of the blockchain is verified (whether the Tx comply with the sets of rules implied on blockchain) by miners.